# Cannot remove C:/ubuntu folder

Tags: 12.04

I recently installed windows 8 and then tried installing ubuntu 12.10 using windows installer. It just did not install. I removed it from the control panel- add or remove programs. Still, there was a C:/ubuntu folder. I could simply not delete it. It is taking so much of my space. I tried shift delete, tuneup shredder, rmdir from command prompt but still the file in the C:/ubuntu/disks folder keeps reappearing after delete.

I tried to install ubuntu again but it just would not. There was a similar post (which is now closed in ubuntu-God knows why as it is very much relevant still) which suggested using lockhunter to rename the folder..i renamed it to ubuntujunk. While, my CD boot helper is getting installed and hopefully I will be able to install ubuntu 12.04 (now left 12.10), what will happen to my ubuntujunk folder...its taking up valuable space...5 GB or more.

Pls help.

Comment: Can you boot from the LiveCD and *remove* it from there?.

Comment: I have to try and see

Answer (score 0):

You can't and you **mustn't do that**! It is one of ubuntu's important folder, last time I force delete it and my computer crashed, then I need to re-install everything. I you remove root.disk your computer will not boot Please see this disaster: http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.hk/2011/08/missing-rootdisk.html and read this from ubuntu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide